# comparison of compact Topological space

Tags: general-topology

comparison  of  compact Toplogical space

Let  $T$  be  a topological space  and $A$  be  a proper  dense  open subsets  of  $T$ .

which of the following statement are  necessarily True ?

$1.)$ If  $T \setminus A$ is  compact  then $T$  is  compact

$2.)$ If  $T$ is  compact  ,then $T \setminus A$ is  compact

I thinks option $1)$ is true take  $A = [0,1] \cup \{2\}$ but im not  not sure  about option $2$

Any hints/solution

Comment: Closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Comment: @ThomasShelby that mean option 2  is  also true ??

Comment: There's no reason for 1 to be true. In a $T_1$ space with limit points you can always take $A=T-\{x\} $ for some limit point $x$ and $T-A$ is compact but $T$ need not be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $T$ to be the reals and $A$ the set $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ which is open and dense. $T\setminus A=\{0\}$ is compact but $T$ is not.

This falsifies 1. The statement 2 does hold as $T\setminus A$ is closed in the compact $T$ and is thus compact by a standard result.